# Pandas Groupby after fitering based on column values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

Hi I am trying to groupby based on three columns and then aggregate/sum of fourth column. I am only interested if Mo_Year column(float) is 10.2019, 11.2019 and 12.2019 and aggregate the sum of last column Amount. 
I tried filtering with goupby as mentioned below. Filtration for `Mo_Year`  is not happening.

Sample dataset as below

```
    Name  Mo_Year    Item  Amount
    A1    10.2019    cat     60
    A2    1.2019     dog     40
    A3    12.2019    cat     10  
    A4    3.2019     dog     30
    A5    4.2019     cat     10
    A1    10.2019    dog     50
    A2    11.2019    cat     30
    A3    3.2019     cat     20
    A4    10.2019    dog     10
    A5    11.2019    cat     70
```

```
df_test = df1.groupby(['Name','Mo_Year', 'Item']).filter(lambda x: (x['Mo_Year'] == 10.2019).any() & (x['Mo_Year'] == 12.2019).any())
```

Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: ```Mo_Year``` is float type.

Comment: ok, can you add how looks final dataframe?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my Header ``` Name     Mo_Year       Item     Amount```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if check [filtration](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#filtration), it working different.

It return all data in groups, if matching condition, else all data in group are removed.

---

If values are floats, need to change `&` to `or`:

```
df_test=(df1.groupby(['Name','Mo_Year', 'Item'])
            .filter(lambda x: (x['Mo_Year'] == 10.2019).any() or 
                              (x['Mo_Year'] == 12.2019).any()))
```

or:

```
df_test=(df1.groupby(['Name','Mo_Year', 'Item'])
            .filter(lambda x: (x['Mo_Year'].isin([10.2019,11.2019,12.2009]).any())
```

But maybe `groupby` shoud be omit, if need filter by condition only:

```
df= df[df['Mo_Year'].isin([10.2019,11.2019,12.2009])]
```

Comment: My silly mistake to add ```&```. I changed to or. Since it's a float type, I tried your first suggestion. But final dataframe has all the rows. No filteration  is happening.

Comment: @Lilly - it is expected, because here filter means - return all groups if match condition. So if at least one value matched, it return all dat a in group. Maybe need last suggestion

Comment: Yes thanks. Makes sense. I am trying the last option to filter first and then group by. But even in that situation, only the first number is getting displayed. Like I get to see only ```10.2019``` data and not the others.

Comment: @Lilly - what is your code? How looks expected output?

Comment: Oopss. sorry my mistake again. I had to correct 2009 to 2019. cut and paste issue. Thanks and appreciate your time ```df= df[df['Mo_Year'].isin([10.2019,11.2019,12.2019])]```  works. I will add the groupby condition on filtered df